# Prevent Scrapy Spider from starting if it's already running

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapyd to schedule spiders and sometimes, depending on the volume of data, a spider will be initiated when an instance is already running. I want to prevent this. I have tried writing a lock file and checking it but I am running into issues because every spider in my project is implementing the lock. Here is what I have:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "my-spider"

    lockFile(name + ".lock")
    ...
```

I understand that the issue is because I am creating the lock in the instance of the MySpider class but I don't know where else to put it. I was thinking of a middlewares component but not sure that would make sense. Ideas?

Comment: I think that it would be simpler to check if the job is finished using the listjobs.json api in Scrapyd (http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#listjobs-json)

Comment: And then what? I don't want to have to check 63 spiders every couple of minutes.

Comment: You can check before scheduling a new spider, if it is already running in the api response.

Comment: Okay, that sounds promising. So I have schedule spiders to run once every 24 hours. How do I get scrapyd to check if it's already running?

Answer (score 0):

Use `listjobs.json` api.

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://localhost:6800/listjobs.json?project=myproject")
```

The response is something like this

```
{"status": "ok",
 "pending": [{"id": "78391cc0fcaf11e1b0090800272a6d06", "spider": "spider1"}],
 "running": [{"id": "422e608f9f28cef127b3d5ef93fe9399", "spider": "spider2", "start_time": "2012-09-12 10:14:03.594664"}],
 "finished": [{"id": "2f16646cfcaf11e1b0090800272a6d06", "spider": "spider3", "start_time": "2012-09-12 10:14:03.594664", "end_time": "2012-09-12 10:24:03.594664"}]}
```

Here you can check if the spider is already running in the `r.json()["running"]` list.
Source: http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#listjobs-json

Comment: Thanks, I get that except that the jobs are scheduled to run every 24 hours autonomously.

Comment: How are you scheduling jobs? Something like celery?

Comment: I am using SpiderKeeper

Comment: SpiderKeeper is a flask app, look at https://github.com/DormyMo/SpiderKeeper/blob/master/SpiderKeeper/app/proxy/contrib/scrapy.py. Maybe you can change how `start_spider()` is implemented, write your own patched version (or raise an issue with SpiderKeeper to add this as a functionality).